# Liquibase : Creating table with column Array of Varchar(100)

Tags: arrays, liquibase, tablecolumn, liquibase-sql

Does Liquibase allow us to create a table column as an Array of nvarchar(100) using XML or YAML changesets.

I mean it is possible to do that within some databases natively.

For example in H2 DB
https://www.h2database.com/html/datatypes.html#array_type

There are other RDBMS as well, which also allow such a columns which are arrays of basic data types like arrays of string/ array of integers etc. My requirement is to implement such a table using Liquibase changeset and underlying H2 DB and subsequently some other DB which also has the array of string column feature.

Comment: I've been trying to find an answer to this question for several days for you with no luck, so I'd suggest that you post it as a feature request on our Idea Board: https://ideas.liquibase.com/tabs/1-under-consideration